# Button percent width re-size issue

Tags: html, css, button

I have buttons

```
#buttons {
/*Div containing the buttons*/
margin-top: 10px;
width: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.navbutton {
/*8 buttons*/
height: 38px;
float: left;
min-width: 60px;
max-width: 140px;
display: inline-block;
width: 12.5%;
background-image: url(button.jpg);
background-size: 100%;
color: white;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #d0d0d0;
border: outset #555 1.5px;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
font-size: 16px;
}

#content {
/*containing everything, centred*/
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 90.54%;
color: white;
border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

and HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="buttons">
        <button type="button" class="navbutton" onclick="location.href='#';" style="color: #149ae7; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;">HOME</button>
        <button type="button" class="navbutton">PART A</button>
        <button type="button" class="navbutton">PART B</button>
        <button type="button" class="navbutton">PART C</button>
        <button type="button" class="navbutton">PART D</button>
        <button type="button" class="navbutton">PART E</button>
        <button type="button" class="navbutton">PART F</button>
        <button type="button" class="navbutton" style="color: #e7db17; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px;">HELP</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the buttons "squish in" as I reduce the width of the browser window? Like [www.dotacinema.com](http://www.dotacinema.com) (but all buttons same size)

Currently it is not working, if I reduce the width of the website everything acts like a single image so nothing is rescaled.

Thanks

Comment: By 'squish in' do you mean the rearrangement of the buttons to take up the whole width, when the browser window is smaller?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with CSS media queries, with which you define new styles for elements when, for example, the width of window is less than 400px.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nejo/TTeUw/).

Relevant code is at the top of CSS:

```
@media(max-width:400px){
   ul li{
    display: block !important;
    width:100% !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    margin-bottom:2px;
   }
}
```